# How can I use runblocking on button click

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

What is the purpose of runblocking?. Can I use it in OnClickListener?. 
Here I am using runblocking{} in OnClickListener
This is my code

```
 mBinding.ivAdd.setOnClickListener{
println("before" + Thread.currentThread().id)
        runBlocking {
            println("in async" + Thread.currentThread().id)

            val job = launch {
                // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
                delay(1000L)
                println("World!" + Thread.currentThread().id)
                mBinding.tvNoDataFound.text = "test"
            }
            println("Hello,")
            println("after hello" + Thread.currentThread().id)
            delay(5000)
            job.join() // wait until child coroutine completes
        }
        println("after runBlocking" + Thread.currentThread().id)
    }
```

It shows error like this

```
 12-20 14:46:31.387 26915-26915/ I/System.out: before1
 12-20 14:46:31.399 26915-26915/ I/System.out: in async1
 12-20 14:46:31.405 26915-26915/ I/System.out: Hello,
 12-20 14:46:31.405 26915-26915/ I/System.out: after hello1
 12-20 14:46:32.410 26915-26937/I/System.out: World!1561
 12-20 14:46:32.422 26915-26937/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
 ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2

   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:907)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18728)
       at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7169)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4347)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4204)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4179)
       at MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$job$1.doResume(MainActivity.kt:164)
       at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:54)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchTask.run(CoroutineDispatcher.kt:123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1388)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:251)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:845)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1674)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1629)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)

12-20 14:46:36.410 26915-26915/I/System.out: after runBlocking1
12-20 14:46:36.410 26915-26915/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 313 frames!  The 
application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

If I use **launch(UI){ }** instead of **launch{ }**, it gives output like below

```
12-20 14:57:11.700 27338-27338/ I/System.out: before1
12-20 14:57:11.710 27338-27338/ I/System.out: in async1
12-20 14:57:11.714 27338-27338/ I/System.out: Hello,
12-20 14:57:11.714 27338-27338/ I/System.out: after hello1
12-20 14:57:16.718 27338-27338/ I/art: Note: end time exceeds epoch:
```

It doesn't print "World" which is come from another coroutine.

Here is another example of runblocking, which use runblocking from onCreate()

```
 println("before runblocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)
        runBlocking {
            println("in runblocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)

            val job = launch(UI) {

                println("In launch " + Thread.currentThread().id)

            }
            println("after launch " + Thread.currentThread().id)

        }
        println("after runBlocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)
```

Output of above code is

```
12-20 15:58:13.253 8588-8588/? I/System.out: before runblocking 1
12-20 15:58:13.266 8588-8588/? I/System.out: in runblocking 1
12-20 15:58:13.271 8588-8588/? I/System.out: after launch 1
12-20 15:58:13.273 8588-8588/? I/System.out: after runBlocking 1
12-20 15:58:13.363 8588-8588/? I/System.out: In launch 1
```

As we expect, "after runblocking" prints at last but it doesn't.
If I use **job.join** to wait completion of sub coroutine, the code is

```
  println("before runblocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)
        runBlocking {
            println("in runblocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)

            val job = launch(UI) {
                println("In launch " + Thread.currentThread().id)
            }
            println("after launch " + Thread.currentThread().id)
            job.join() // wait until child coroutine completes
        }
        println("after runBlocking " + Thread.currentThread().id)
```

Output of above code is

```
12-20 16:10:43.234 9194-9194/ I/System.out: before runblocking 1
12-20 16:10:43.249 9194-9194/ I/System.out: in runblocking 1
12-20 16:10:43.253 9194-9194/ I/System.out: after launch 1
```

Then what is the expected behavior of runblocking?. How can I use runblocking?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're blocking the code, the operation `mBinding.tvNoDataFound.text = "test"` runs on a pool worker thread.

> [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/run-blocking.html) is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.

In your case it should not be used. If you need to do background work, you should never block the UI thread. This happens regardless of using `launch` or `launch(UI)`. The latter just makes everything run on the same thread and blocks even before the join.

So try not to block the UI thread and schedule a view update later via `launch(UI)` or with the standard [`View.post {}`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: Isn't `runBlocking` used to block the main thread while all the coroutines complete their job? I am still confused about the runBlocking execution sequence

Comment: Seems to me like this: Runs new coroutine and blocks current thread _interruptibly_ until its completion.